# Flutter: Navigate route for custom Appbar

Tags: flutter, appbar

A custom AppBar is created by error (error: Undefined name 'context') when adding navigation routes
Below is the custom widget

```
Widget customAppBarTest(String title, bool backButton, bool home, bool about) {
  return AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Center(
      child: Text(title),
    ),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('Go previous screen');
          Navigator.pop(context);
          //Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
    actions: [
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('Go home');
/*            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const HomeMenu(),
              ),
            );*/
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.home))
    ],
  );
}
```

I have no issue without using the default AppBar, but needs to use the customAppBarTest for easier code management

Comment: Make `context` a function parameter

Comment: How to pass the context value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `BuildContext context` parameter in that function

```
Widget customAppBarTest(BuildContext context, String title, bool backButton, bool home, bool about) {
  return AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Center(
      child: Text(title),
    ),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('Go previous screen');
          Navigator.pop(context);
          //Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
    actions: [
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('Go home');
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const HomeMenu(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.home))
    ],
  );
}
```